# Derivation of the formula for Electric Potential Energy

Tags: electricity, potential-energy, integration

I just learnt the formula for calculating Electric Potential Energy

$W=\frac{1}{C}\int_0^Qqdq = \frac{1}{C}[\frac{1}{2}q^2]_0^Q=\frac{Q^2}{2C}$

I understand the methodology, but what I do not understand is how one can extract the $\frac{1}{C}$ as if it were a constant, when C itself actually depends on q and Q (as $C=\frac{Q}{V}$) and Q grows as a result of adding more q.

Can somebody help out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an important misconception. When considering a capacitor with capacitance C, the capacitance is a geometric quantity. It only depends on the structure of the capacitor, so it does not depend on the charge or potential. Your formula just tells you how much charge Q you can store given a potential V and a capacitance C.

Comment: Thank you!
One more question, though: I learnt that the Capacitance of a cable depends on the area of the positive plate and the distance between the positive and the negative plates, mathematically: C = εo·(A/D). We arrived at that conclusion by plugging V=Ed=(Qd)/(εοA) into C=Q/V. 

If Capacitance depends on area and distance, /through/ the definition of V, does that not imply that Capacitance depends at least on Potential? (thanks to your answer I now understand that it does not depend on Q, but I am having difficulty seeing how it does not depend on V, given the above).

Comment: You almost gave the answer yourself. Look at the formula $C = \varepsilon_0\frac{A}{d}$. All these values are fundamental/geometrical units and hence the capacitance does not depend on the potential. You merely used the formula for the potential as way to find the capacitance.

Comment: Thanks once more! One last thing: we use the formula C=Q/V in many exercises to determine what the Q is. If it only tells me how much charge /can/ be stored, and not how much /is/ actually stored, then how can I use this formula? Do I assume that the capacitance is "being used to the max", storing the full charge that it can store?

Comment: The capacitor will charge until it is fully charged. This time is important when considering circuits with resistors and inductors. But for these one needs to solve differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

For adding more q it will consequently increase the V so the ratio of q/V remains constant if I thought your way.